# Cruise Control .NET not fails build when source control exception occurs

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Cruise Control .NET not fails build when source control exception occurs and this is very unexpected because shows build status succes in tray icon. I tried to use modificationDelaySeconds,maxSourceControlRetries,sourceControlErrorHandling, stopProjectOnReachingMaxSourceControlRetries blocks without any result. I tried also to check connection to svn server in prebuild and publisher block, but prebuild block it's excute after source control block so it never happen and publisher block cannot fail build...

Comment: Post the build log so people can help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a question here?

If you're saying that cruise control will report a source control failure as a successful build then yes I believe I understand what you mean.

Cruise control will report the status of the last build. 
As a source control failure doesn't yield a build, it cannot figure in the last build status.

Comment: Question was is there any way to force that build failure when source control exception occurs.

Comment: Semantically there cannot be a built failure if the build has never happened. However the project does hold information about the failure. It depends how you want to use/visualise it.

Comment: For example a project has an IntegrationStatus which will hold "Exception" in your case.

Comment: But this Exception status holds until publisher end his work, after that become success once again and this is treacherous. So is there cruise control block/option to hold that status until next build ?

Comment: If you have the web dashboard installed or use the CCTray app then the project will show that the last build succeeded but the project is in an exception state. The status is preserved between builds. Where/why are you trying to find out the previous status?

Comment: But no one looks on build summary on dashboard if CCTray shows that everything is ok. Thats the reason

Comment: No matter. Solution is to write own plugin to fail in that situation.